# Rails - Simplifying calculation models & objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, model

I have asked a few questions about this recently and I am getting where I need to go, but have perhaps not been specific enough in my last questions to get all the way there. So, I am trying to put together a structure for calculating some metrics based on app data, which should be flexible to allow additional metrics to be added easily (and securely), and also relatively simple to use in my views.

The overall goal is that I will be able to have a custom helper that allows something like the following in my view:

```
calculate_metric(@metrics.where(:name => 'profit'),@customer,@start_date,@end_date)
```

This should be fairly self explanatory - the name can be substituted to any of the available metric names, and the calculation can be performed for any customer or group of customers, for any given time period.

Where the complexity arises is in how to store the formula for calculating the metric - I have shown below the current structure that I have put together for doing this:

[image]

You will note that the key models are metric, operation, operation_type and operand. This kind of structure works ok when the formula is very simple, like profit - one would only have two operands, `@customer.sales.selling_price.sum` and `@customer.sales.cost_price.sum`, with one operation of type subtraction. Since we don't need to store any intermediate values, `register_target` will be `1`, as will `return_register`.

I don't think I need to write out a full example to show where it becomes more complicated, but suffice to say if I wanted to calculate the percentage of customers with email addresses for customers who opened accounts between two dates (but did not necessarily buy), this would become much more complex since the helper function would need to know how to handle the date variations.

As such, it seems like this structure is overly complicated, and would be hard to use for anything other than a simple formula - can anyone suggest a better way of approaching this problem?

EDIT: On the basis of the answer from Railsdog, I have made some slight changes to my model, and re-uploaded the diagram for clarity. Essentially, I have ensured that the reporting_category model can be used to hide intermediate operands from users, and that operands that may be used in user calculations can be presented in a categorised format. All I need now is for someone to assist me in modifying my structure to allow an operation to use *either* an actual operand or the result of a previous operation in a rails-esqe way.

Thanks for all of your help so far!

Comment: I've marked Railsdog's comments as the answer, as it has helped get to the right level, and I will ask a separate question about a railsy way to allow an operation to use an actual operand or the result of a previous operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oy vey.  It's been years (like 15) since I did something similar to what it seems like you are attempting. My app was used to model particulate deposition rates for industrial incinerators.

In the end, all the computations boiled down to two operands and an operator (order of operations, parentheticals, etc).  Operands were either constants, db values, or the result of another computation (a pointer to another computation).  Any Operand (through model methods) could evaluate itself, whether that value was intrinsic, or required a child computation to evaluate itself first.

The interface wasn't particularly elegant (that's the real challenge I think), but the users were scientists, and they understood the computation decomposition.

Thinking about your issue, I'd have any individual Metric able to return it's value, and create the necessary methods to arrive at that answer.  After all, a single metric just needs to know how to combine it's two operands using the indicated operator. If an operand is itself a metric, you just ask it what it's value is.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying correctly, I could modify the operation model to simply have left_operand and right_operand, and any given operand could be the value of a previous operation? That seems like it would be sensible, though it could result in an enormous number of operands (i.e. if I needed to add 10 different sales types together, I would need a lot of operands). I would be interested to see if anyone can assist in translating this kind of structure into something rails-esque (specifically in terms of how to reference an operand to the result of a previous calculation).

Comment: Yes, it does result in a large number of operands, but the definition of an operand can be reusable. One of the issues we had dealt with was the "jiggering" (that's the real client term - always makes me laugh) of a formula to test a new idea.  They wanted high reusability of a complex setup when we designed that app, so they were able to name certain sub-computations which encapsulated a set of work.  You could do similar. You need only define a specific aggregation Metric once, then reuse that Metric wherever needed. By dealer, by region, whatever.